# XLib windows auto-alignment performance

Tags: x11, xlib, window-managers

In XLib based application, I need to make the child window to be resized after the parent window. (For example, in order to make the child window to take the whole client area of the parent window)

I am processing the ConfigureNotify event of the parent window and resizing the child window when needed.

In generally it works properly. But there is a delay between resizing the parent window (for example when the user resizes the window dragging the edge) and the event received by the application.

Because of this delay, the child window(s) takes its proper size only some time after the user stops to move the edges. This way, some bad flicker appears on the screen and the user interface looks really sluggish.

I can see the similar behavior in many Linux programs.

How this problem can be fixed? Or at least, how to make the delay significantly smaller?

I tried to ignore some of the ConfigureNotify events by processing only the last received event and it helps a little, but not enough.

**Update:**

After some research I found that the problem is due to the asynchronous nature of the WM-application interaction. While the application resizes and redraws the child window, the window manager continues to resize the parent window. So, when the process of the resize/realign/redraw finishes, the parent window has another size, another event is posted to the event queue and everything must be started from the beginning.

Comment: Try calling `XFlush()` after resizing the child window.

Comment: There is no effect at all.

Comment: @n.m. There is an update in the question - some more experiments results.

Comment: Um, XSync will be indeed useless here, it was stupid to suggest it :( Have you tried to also ignore intermediate Expose events and only process the last one?

Comment: @n.m. But I still need the child windows to be updated during resize. What I actually need is to make WM to not resize the parent widow until the children are not fully aligned. This way, the window resize will be a little bit slower, but a lot more smoother.

Comment: You definitely do NOT want to change WM behaviour. You want timely updates that do not happen so often as to slow everything down. You handle resizes and repaints the same way. If there was a resize/repaint N millisec ago or less, *and* there are still events in the queue, ignore the event and set a flag 'redraw/resize needed'. Do that when you don't have events in the queue *or* N millisec has passed since the last action.

Comment: Alternatively just do with repaints what you have done with resizes, i.e. process only the last event in the queue.

Comment: Another source of flicker is clearing the window before repaint. Try to eliminate this. You may need to play with window gravity. If your window contents depends on its size in a non-trivial way (e.g. you are zooming on a vector graphic) you may need to double-buffer your window.

Comment: @n.m. I don't want to change the WM behavior. I want to synchronize its behavior with the application. BTW, all mentioned repaints are double buffered - there is no flicker because of clearing.

Comment: Let me phrase it this way. Suppose the user grabs a window border and starts moving it at 25 pixels per second. What do you want the WM to do? You have no way to control it from your app but perhaps you can change the WM settings to better suit your tastes.

Comment: [A small example](http://pastebin.com/RJyJpx0T). I don't see any flicker at all with it. If you do, perhaps you need a faster machine/GPU. If you don't see flicker with a small example but do see it with your program, then obviously there's some other reason of the problem.

Comment: If I make the repaint more slow and complicated (e.g. draw 10000 small rectangles) then I do see flicker. But this happens even with one window, i.e. it has nothing to do with subwindow resizing. The trick is to do all the drawing to a pixmap and then set this pixmap as your window background.

Comment: @n.m. Can you provide some help with building your code. Note, I am not a C/C++ programmer. Only read C/C++ a little. My code is in assembly language.

Comment: `gcc progname.c -lX11 -o progname` (you may need to add `-L/path/to/X11/libs` before `-lX11`).

Comment: @n.m. Thanks. [Here](http://pastebin.com/LigrCGvK) is the variant of your source that illustrates the problem I want to solve. Note that there is no "flicker" but the child window always has to catch up the size of the parent window.

Comment: OK now I see the lag. I'm not sure it is even possible to do something with it, short of disposing of the subordinate window altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ConfigureNotify event handling and get the current parent size in the expose processing. This ignores the queued Configure Notify events the give a history of the parent size rather that the current parent window size.

So modifying the code you posted in the [comments](http://pastebin.com/LigrCGvK).

```
if (e.type == Expose) {
  if (e.xexpose.count == 0) {
    Window r;
    int x,y;
    unsigned int wd,ht, bw, dep;
    XGetGeometry(d,w,&r,&x,&y,&wd,&ht,&bw,&dep);
    width = wd - 20;
    height = ht - 20;
    XMoveResizeWindow (d, ww, 10, 10, width, height);
    for (i=0;i<1000;i++) {
      XFillRectangle(d, ww, DefaultGC(d, s), 20, 20, 10, 10);
      XFillRectangle(d, ww, DefaultGC(d, s), width-30, height-30, 10, 10);
      XFillRectangle(d, ww, DefaultGC(d, s), 20, height-30, 10, 10);
      XFillRectangle(d, ww, DefaultGC(d, s), width-30, 20, 10, 10);
    }
  }
}
```

Update: To fix the lack of expose events, add the following:

```
if (e.type == ConfigureNotify) {
{
    while (XCheckTypedWindowEvent(d, w, ConfigureNotify, &e) == True);
    width = e.xconfigure.width - 20;
    height = e.xconfigure.height - 20;
    XMoveResizeWindow (d, ww, 10, 10, width, height);
}
```

This will cause some more expose events. The `XCheckTypedWindowEvent` may not be necessary, it removes any all the ConfigureNotify events from the queue leaving the last one found in `e`.

Comment: The code you are using as a prototype redraws the child window very fast and because of this, the negative effect almost invisible even on the base variant. Try your suggestion with the code modified by me: [This one](http://pastebin.com/LigrCGvK) - it has artificially slowed redraw, so the effect is very visible. Unfortunately your suggestion has very little effect in this case.

Comment: The code you point to is the same as I was using, the only real problem I could see was the window decoration flickering badly which my change greatly reduced.  Which window manager are you using? I'm using kwm, the KDE WM.

Comment: I am using OpenBox (with LXDE). Maybe your computer is too fast. I am testing on a netbook. So maybe you should increase the cycle length from 1000 to 10000 or even more. The result should look like the corner of the child window is connected to the corner of the parent by some rubber band and follows after it with some delay.

Comment: I had to use 100000 to get the effect.  The expose events are the problem.  Got the same results with openbox on my raspberry pi (using 1000).

Comment: So, you have fast video card. But the expose events are not the problem. You can always have very complex drawing algorithm or slow enough computer. But the behavior of the program should be always good.

Comment: The behaviour cannot be good with your example, the window manager (a separate process) is redrawing the frame of the window and sending the events (to another process) but the code is taking too long to process the events. You need to improve the event performance. E.g. if you just put sleep 10 in the event loop, you can't expect good behaviour.

Comment: The discussed problem happens because the WM resizes the parent window very fast, while the child needs some time in order to redraw itself. This time is not so big. If for example the WM is able to wait a little for application to redraw/resize the child, the whole performance will not be affected, but the WM will not generate so many resize events and the child window will always be the exact size without this "rubber band effect".

Comment: Ok I see what you're getting at - answer changed again

Comment: Hey, it really works this way. It is a very good idea to not process ConfigureNotify events. You only have to add in the answer that the ConfigureNotify handler has to be removed at all.

Comment: When I tried to use the ideas from this answer, unexpected problem appeared. :( When the child windows covers the entire client area of the parent, X11 server stops to generate expose events for the parent window. This way, whole resize engine stops to work properly. In the discussed example, this effect can be reproduced by placing the child on 0,0 and removing 20px width/height shrink. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, the problem appears only when the window get smaller. It is because after parent resize, there is still no area to need repaint, so no expose event is generated.