# Xlib ConfigureRequest with custom configuration not working

Tags: python, c, x11, xlib, window-managers

I am using python and python3-xlib (which is a pure python implementation of the Xlib interface but basically is very similar to the C Xlib). For educational purposes, I am trying to create a simple window manager which should be able to force windows to have some specific sizes, when they are opened. In my example, I want to force the windows to have a width and height of 500px.

I listen for the ConfigureRequest event and for the MapRequest event. If I don't change width and height, but directly pass the hints of the opening window without changing them, to the window's configuration, everything works as expected.

However, when I specify a size that is not the intended size of the newly opening window, the MapRequest is delayed by more than 3 seconds (window becomes visible >3s after ConfigureRequest). This was the case, when I tested this using `xterm`. When I tested `gnome-terminal`, the MapRequest was fired before the ConfigureRequest, became immediately visible, **but did not redraw** (although I could close it by blindly typing `exit` <kbd>Return</kbd>).

This is obviously not the expected behavior. Am I doing anything wrong?

The relevant code:

```
def handle_event(self):
    try:
        event = self.display.next_event()
    except Xlib.error.ConnectionClosedError:
        print("The connection to display '"+self.display.get_display_name()+"' was closed by the server")
        print("Exiting now")
        sys.exit(0)
    if event.type in self.event_map:
        self.event_map[event.type](event) # calls on_configure_request or on_map_request depending on event type
```

.

```
def handle_configure_request(self, event):
    window = event.window
    args = { 'border_width': 3 }
    if event.value_mask & Xlib.X.CWX:
        args['x'] = event.x
    if event.value_mask & Xlib.X.CWY:
        args['y'] = event.y
    if event.value_mask & Xlib.X.CWWidth:
        args['width'] = event.width
    if event.value_mask & Xlib.X.CWHeight:
        args['height'] = event.height
    if event.value_mask & Xlib.X.CWSibling:
        args['sibling'] = event.above
    if event.value_mask & Xlib.X.CWStackMode:
        args['stack_mode'] = event.stack_mode
    args["width"] = 500
    args["height"] = 500
    window.configure(**args)
    print("Configured") # printed twice for every window -> is this normal?
```

.

```
def on_map_request(self, event):
    print("Mapping now") # when width and height are changed like above, this is printed more than 3s after on_configure_request when testing with xterm
    event.window.map()
    print("Mapped")
```

Comment: https://git.suckless.org/dwm/file/dwm.c.html#l614

Peeking at the source for my favorite window manager, it seems to make a call to `XMoveResizeWindow()` if it's going to explicitly change the window size to something other than the intended size.

Also see this other question that also seems to be related to the performance problems you are observing:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504025/xlib-windows-auto-alignment-performance